# How do I read the information from multiple txt files?

Tags: python, multithreading, file

This is my code for reading my files from my folder but idk how can I read its information of each one.

```
import os

def readfiles(folder):

    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        print(file)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder,file)):
            devolverArchivos(os.path.join(folder,file))

readfiles("/home/citlali/Modelos")
```

Comment: for text files, use `open("text.txt").read().splitlines()`

Comment: But I have 10 txt file, idk how to write that for 10 files.

Comment: do you mean to write the 10 text files into 1 text file?

Comment: What exactly will your code be doing with the information read? Writing it *where*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.walk()` like below:

```
import os

temp = {}

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".txt"):
            # Your function goes here!
            with open(filepath) as f:
                temp[filepath] = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could read text files using `open("text.txt").read().splitlines()`. For example

```
import os

def readfiles(folder):
    result1 = []
    result2 = []
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if file[-4:] == '.txt':
            result1.append(open(file).read().splitlines())
            result2.extend(open(file).read().splitlines())
    print(result1)
    print(result2)

readfiles("/home/citlali/Modelos")
```

Depending on how you would like to compile the results, `list.append()` will append the *list* of text lines, whereas `list.extend()` will add individual text lines (ie, merge 2 lists into 1).

To write all text files into 1 text file, you could try:

```
def readfiles(folder):
    with open('result.txt', 'a') as write_file:
        for file in os.listdir(folder):
            if file[-4:] == '.txt':
                write_file.write(', '.join(open(file).read().splitlines()))
                write_file.write('\n')
    write_file.close()

readfiles("/home/citlali/Modelos")
```